# grep for stuff in multiple git repositories

Tags: git, gitosis

So I've inherited a fairly large code base from some other developers, with code stored in various git repositories.

Sometimes, it's hard to know which project a particular piece of code might lie in, or if that piece of code even exists in git.

What I want to be able to do is grep ALL the projects for some particular piece of text.

I'm using gitosis, so all the git repositories are stored in /home/git/repositories with a structure like:

```
/home/git/repositories
  |- project1
    |- HEAD
    |- branches
    |- config
    |- description
    |- hooks
    |- info
    |- objects
    |- refs
  |- project2
    |- ...
```

I've tried doing a recursive grep for stuff in the objects directories like this:

```
grep -Hr "text" /home/git/repositories/*/objects
```

This fails to work as I intend of course, because the objects are stored in git's custom format.

What do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `git grep` with a ref or `--no-index`:

```
cd /home/git/repositories
for i in *; do ( cd $i; git grep text HEAD ); done
```

Comment: If you're looking for a particular piece of code, as opposed to text in a commit message, you could also use `git log -S"<string>"` here. It's called a [pickaxe search.](http://gitfu.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/the-pickaxe-finding-changes-was-never-easier/)

Comment: the problem is that the folders in /home/git/repositories aren't actually git working trees so git grep doesn't work on them.

Comment: @python_noob git grep does work in a bare repo if you specify a ref (eg, HEAD)

Comment: Well, that's frustrating.  I just went searching for a way to do this that is better than a simple shell wrapper, and the only answer I find is my own from 7 years ago! Surely there is some better tooling now!

Comment: I've filed a feature request: https://public-inbox.org/git/MN2PR11MB3663C042590097D7A7F4B2409DF10@MN2PR11MB3663.namprd11.prod.outlook.com/

Answer (score 5):

I know its old question but if you use command line you can add this to `bash_profile` or `bashrc`

```
ggrep() {
    find . -type d -name .git | while read line; do
        (
        cd $line/..
        cwd=$(pwd)
        echo "$(tput setaf 2)$cwd$(tput sgr0)"
        git grep -n "$@"
        )
    done
}
```

basic gist of above function is to search of all directories that contains `.git` and output first that directory then file along with line number where that token occurs

then go to `/home/git/repositories` and search using

`ggrep "InvalidToken"`

it will output like this

```
/home/git/org/repo1
/home/git/org/repo2
/home/git/org/repo3
/home/git/org/repo3
lib/v3/Utility.pm:59:         code              => 'InvalidToken',
lib/v3/Utility.pm:142:        code              => "InvalidToken",
```

you can also pass flags like `ggrep -i "search"` (for case insensitive search)

Comment: Nice solution. One observation from my usage is that because I know the repositories are all direct descendants of my current folder I added `-maxdepth 2` to the `find` command's arguments, which makes this execute a lot quicker for me.

Comment: I had to add `--no-pager` to see output as described in this answer (all at once instead of reviewing results folder by folder)

Answer (score 2):

Use [multi](https://github.com/coryfklein/multi). It was written specifically to `git grep` through multiple repositories at once.

```
$ ls
vim spring-framework gradle phantomjs
$ multi -i "fantastic"
vim
====================================================
runtime/doc/quotes.txt:VIM 4.5 is really a fantastic editor.  It has sooooo many features and more
runtime/doc/quotes.txt:fantastic it is! (Tony Nugent, Australia)
spring-framework
====================================================
gradle
====================================================
subprojects/docs/src/docs/userguide/ant.xml:        simply by relying on Groovy, and the fantastic <literal>AntBuilder</literal>.
subprojects/docs/src/docs/userguide/buildScriptsTutorial.xml:            relying on Groovy. Groovy is shipped with the fantastic <literal>AntBuilder</literal>. Using Ant tasks
subprojects/docs/src/docs/userguide/ideSupport.xml:            if you do this you have a fantastic IDE support for developing Gradle scripts. Of course if you use
phantomjs
====================================================
test/ghostdriver-test/fixtures/common/macbeth.html:<A NAME=1.3.55>Are ye fantastical, or that indeed</A><br>
test/ghostdriver-test/fixtures/common/macbeth.html:<A NAME=1.3.148>My thought, whose murder yet is but fantastical,</A><br>
```

Comment: Multi is still a great tool for this use-case in 2021.